# C++ convert integer to hex string for Color in Graphicsmagick

Tags: c++, colors, hex, graphicsmagick

How can i convert an integer ranging from 0 to 255 to a string with exactly two chars, containg the hexadecimal representation of the number?

Example

input: 180
output: "B4"

My goal is to set the grayscale color in Graphicsmagick. So, taking the same example i want the following final output:

"#B4B4B4"

so that i can use it for assigning the color: Color("#B4B4B4");

Should be easy, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to. This is an easier way:

```
ColorRGB(red/255., green/255., blue/255.)
```

Comment: I have another question, how can i set the transparency of this color?

Comment: @Alp: please refer to the [documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Color.html) of the library you're using.

Comment: I don't see how to use the ColorRGB class and setting the alpha channel to a custom value.

Comment: I tried: `Color color = ColorRGB(R, G, B); color.alpha(.5);` but it does not seem to work, still no opacity.

Comment: @Alp: this is how it is supposed to work. If it doesn't, it means that the problem is somewhere else (probably at the point you use the color).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native formatting features of the IOStreams part of the C++ Standard Library, like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>

std::string getHexCode(unsigned char c) {

   // Not necessarily the most efficient approach,
   // creating a new stringstream each time.
   // It'll do, though.
   std::stringstream ss;

   // Set stream modes
   ss << std::uppercase << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;

   // Stream in the character's ASCII code
   // (using `+` for promotion to `int`)
   ss << +c;

   // Return resultant string content
   return ss.str();
}

int main() {
   // Output: "B4, 04"
   std::cout << getHexCode(180) << ", " << getHexCode(4); 
}
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/st1Uh)

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf` using the `%x` format specifier. Alternatively, `strtol` specifying the base as 16.

```
#include<cstdio>

int main()
{

    int a = 180;
    printf("%x\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to insist upon using legacy C functionality, include `cstdio` not `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: While i agree with the cstdio comment(and I made the change too) I dont think theres nothing wrong in using legacy C functionality in C++.

Comment: Nor do I (though I think there's a difference between using it and _recommending_ it. :P)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Well if using is not bad recommending cant be bad either.

Comment: Hardly. Just because an experienced C++ programmer knows enough about what he's doing to use the odd bit of legacy C here and there safely, doesn't mean it's wise to encourage a beginner to do it. A bit like how I use cplusplus.com as my reference because I am experienced enough to spot the errors; not in a million years would I _recommend_ it as a resource to anyone who is not.